# MigLayout Specific Layout

Tags: java, miglayout

I have been trying to make a layout with MigLayout that consists of 3 panels, one on the right, one on top, and one that fills the rest of the space.

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions possible. I provide two examples.
In both examples we also set the preferred width and height of 
the panels. Normally, the panels would derive their preferred with from 
their children.

The first layout is done with the `dock` constraint.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutThreePanels extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutThreePanels() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Three panels");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout());

        JPanel pnl1 = new JPanel();
        pnl1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        JPanel pnl2 = new JPanel();
        pnl2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        JPanel pnl3 = new JPanel();
        pnl3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());


        add(pnl2, "w 40, dock east");
        add(pnl1, "h 40, dock north");
        add(pnl3, "w 250, h 200, dock center");

        pack();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutThreePanels ex = new MigLayoutThreePanels();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The three panels are docked to east, north, and center. Additional spaces between
panels can be created with the gap constraints.

[image: First solution]

In the second example, we use utilize the grid structure.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutThreePanels2 extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutThreePanels2() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Three panels");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("gap 3 3"));

        JPanel pnl1 = new JPanel();
        pnl1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        JPanel pnl2 = new JPanel();
        pnl2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        JPanel pnl3 = new JPanel();
        pnl3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        add(pnl1, "h 40, growx");
        add(pnl2, "w 40, spany 2, growy, wrap");
        add(pnl3, "w 250, h 200, grow, push");

        pack();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutThreePanels2 ex = new MigLayoutThreePanels2();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In this example, we also set some gaps between the cells and container insets.

[image: Second example]